# Import header for several ios release?

Tags: iphone, ios, header, versioning

I just wonder if i have to check the current ios release when importing my header. I have an app which use os5 framework. So if i want my app to run in former release, do i have to conditionnaly import my header ? Or do i have to manage it in the implementation ?

eg : if i want to use Twitter/Twitter.h but want my app to run in 4.0. 
is the solution :

Something like :

```
#if CURRENT_OS > __IPHONE_5_0
import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#endif
```

Or

```
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
... 
- (void) myMethod
{
  NSComparisonResult r = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"5.0"];
    if ( r >= 0 ) 
    {
        //do the thing
    }
    else
    {
       // do the workarround

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

br,
Smazimute

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is valid only during compiling. This means it is not useful to check iOS version at runtime.
You can use it to differentiate two targets in the same project (for example free and paid version of your app).

The second solution is valid at runtime, so I think it is the best solution to do something on a specific iOS version, but unfortunately it is unuseful when importing frameworks.
To check iOS version use this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

If your target is just import a specific framework not supported in older iOS, then the only solution you have it is to **weakly link** it.

Take a look at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html